# how connect mogodb atlas to java EE 8 Framework with jpa through hibernate ogm?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, mongodb-atlas, java-ee-8, hibernate-ogm

so i want to connect a mongodb atlas cluster to a jpa project

i could connect to mongodb local with this repo :
https://github.com/i0712326/java-ee-hibernate-mongodb/tree/main/java-ee-09-hibernate-ogm

but how much i changed its persistanse.xml file to able to connect to atlas it didnt work...
i used almost all of property in this page :
https://github.com/WiPeK/JavaEE-Bank/blob/5446e1c0fc87b7d4ef28e89bd3c5542de62ecaa7/shared/src/main/resources/META-INF/mongo-persistence.xml

i think problem is from  host property so
i used this property:

```
  <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.host" value="cluster0-shard-00-00.dd0ui.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01.dd0ui.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02.dd0ui.mongodb.net:27017 "/>
```

then this error comes up :

```
           Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: OGM001203: Unable to find or initialize a connection to the MongoDB server
at deployment.java-ee-09-hibernate-ogm.war//org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.impl.MongoDBDatastoreProvider.createMongoClient(MongoDBDatastoreProvider.java:133)
at deployment.java-ee-09-hibernate-ogm.war//org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.impl.MongoDBDatastoreProvider.start(MongoDBDatastoreProvider.java:108)
... 43 more
          Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "27017,cluster0-shard-00-01.dd0ui.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02.dd0ui.mongodb.net:27017"
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
at deployment.java-ee-09-hibernate-ogm.war//com.mongodb.ServerAddress.<init>(ServerAddress.java:85)
at deployment.java-ee-09-hibernate-ogm.war//org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.impl.MongoDBDatastoreProvider.createMongoClient(MongoDBDatastoreProvider.java:124)
... 44 more
```

i used this property:

```
       <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.host" value="cluster0-shard-00-00.dd0ui.mongodb.net"/>
```

then this error show:

```
            Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: OGM001214: Unable to connect to MongoDB instance cluster0-shard-00-00.dd0ui.mongodb.net:27017
at deployment.java-ee-09-hibernate-ogm.war//org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.impl.MongoDBDatastoreProvider.extractDatabase(MongoDBDatastoreProvider.java:182)
at deployment.java-ee-09-hibernate-ogm.war//org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.impl.MongoDBDatastoreProvider.start(MongoDBDatastoreProvider.java:110)
... 43 more
                 Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 5000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=Unknown, servers=[{address=cluster0-shard-00-00.dd0ui.mongodb.net:27017, type=Unknown, state=Connecting}]
at deployment.java-ee-09-hibernate-ogm.war//com.mongodb.BaseCluster.getDescription(BaseCluster.java:128)
at deployment.java-ee-09-hibernate-ogm.war//com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.getClusterDescription(DBTCPConnector.java:396)
at deployment.java-ee-09-hibernate-ogm.war//com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.getMaxBsonObjectSize(DBTCPConnector.java:641)
at deployment.java-ee-09-hibernate-ogm.war//com.mongodb.Mongo.getMaxBsonObjectSize(Mongo.java:641)
at deployment.java-ee-09-hibernate-ogm.war//com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.find(DBCollectionImpl.java:81)
at deployment.java-ee-09-hibernate-ogm.war//com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.find(DBCollectionImpl.java:66)
at deployment.java-ee-09-hibernate-ogm.war//com.mongodb.DB.getCollectionNames(DB.java:512)
at deployment.java-ee-09-hibernate-ogm.war//com.mongodb.DB.collectionExists(DB.java:555)
at deployment.java-ee-09-hibernate-ogm.war//org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.impl.MongoDBDatastoreProvider.extractDatabase(MongoDBDatastoreProvider.java:173)
... 44 more
```

hibernate-core-4.3.8.final

hibernate-ogm-mongodb-4.1.2.final

mongo-java-driver-2.12.4

Comment: Hi, please describe your situation a bit more detailed. Your question is quite open, so please focus your question too. Provide an example maybe, what your code looks like.

Comment: You are using old dependencies. Is that by choice? The latest Hibernate OGM is 5.4.1.Final

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dependencies you are using are pretty old. I'm not sure they support MongoDB Atlas, they don't support setting multiple hosts in the configuration property.
That's why you are having the `NumberFormatException`.

The latest Hibernate OGM version available is 5.4.1.Final. Unless you have strict requirements about the dependency to use, I would try to use that one: https://hibernate.org/ogm/releases/5.4/

Comment: yes...problem was old dependencies...why when i use maven there is no need to add org models to wildfly?...could i hava your linkedin id?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question